# Create menu dynamically based on user's role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

How do I create a menu in a ASP.NET MVC2 Master Page, dynamically based on the current user's "role"?

Comment: Do you have a specific number of master pages or do you create them on the fly as well? If there are a fixed number, @Henk's suggestion works well. Otherwise you will have to have a loop that creates the menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest and most straightforward way would be to simply add an `if` statement in the view markup:

```
<% if (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin")) { %>
   <%= Html.ActionLink("Admin Tools Index", "Index", "Admin") %>
   <%= Html.ActionLink("Admin Dashboard", "Dashboard", "Admin") %>
<% } %>
```

Or, you can separate out several items pertaining to a specific role into a partial view:

```
<% if (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin")) { %>
   <% Html.RenderPartial("AdminMenu"); %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about MVC but in 'normal' ASP.NET it is possible to select a MasterPage at runtime.

Comment: I think the OP is more interested in the dynamic generation of the menu, rather than selecting an entire master page...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `sitemap` file to generate menus then you can probably do it in there. If not, then it depends.